# Is there any particular reason why FileStream doesn't fill the buffer after certain Read() calls, leading to suboptimal ReadFile() API calls?

Tags: c#, winapi, stream, filesystems

I have been looking into optimizing some code recently, turning this :

```
for (int i = 0; i < count ; i++)
{
    stream.ReadByte();
}
```

into this :

```
stream.Read(buffer, 0, count);
```

However, using some API monitoring tool, I have notified this cause ReadFile() API calls of very small size, compared to before:

Before (default 4K buffer size):

```
ReadFile 4096
ReadFile 4096
ReadFile 4096
ReadFile 4096
...
```

After:

```
ReadFile 4096
ReadFile 8
ReadFile 4096
ReadFile 4096
ReadFile 4
ReadFile 4096
ReadFile 16
ReadFile 4096
...
```

So it looks less optimized than the code before (at least on Win32 API point of view).

I took a look at FileStream [implementation](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/filestream.cs,e23a38af5d11ddd3):

When buffer is empty (or there is not enough bytes left for what is requested) :

- `ReadByte()` will always fill a new buffer (so it always does a 4K read in this case).
- `Read(array, offset, count)` will, however, first give you what is left in the buffer (eg: 8 bytes) then will perform a ReadFile() API call for the rest (eg: 4 bytes), leaving buffer empty ! It's only next Read() call that buffer will be filled (this time doing a 4K read).

**Is this an implementation design choice (something we cannot explain why it's like that), or is there a particular reason to do this ?** (Eg: stream contract that need to be respected).

At first I thought that Read() was never supposed to read more than what you asked for but that not always the case. For example a Read() that empty the buffer (0 bytes left) followed by a small Read() (eg: 4 bytes) will fill the buffer completely, thus reading more than what is asked for (4096 bytes instead of 4).

Comment: Why would you want to buffer only one byte?  Buffering requires more instructions and more memory.  It assume when you read only one byte you are doing your own buffering.

Comment: My guess is that it's trying to avoid copying around large amounts of data from its internal buffer to your array. So if you ask for a bunch of data and pass in an array to populate, it will read directly into your array, rather than reading into an internal buffer and then copying to your array. Obviously it can't avoid this if it's already filled up its internal buffer, but given the choice of filling the internal buffer and then copying that to your array, vs reading into your array directly, it's choosing the latter.

Comment: Seems logical to me. No extra byte is read when it's not needed. ReadByte has to give back EOF or 1 byte and choice is to never read bytes 1 by 1, so it always triggers a buffer load if not EOF. On the contrary, Read doesn't read extra bytes when it's not needed.

Comment: Note that the underlying OS will still be buffering (unless you specify `FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING`, which is indirectly supported).

Comment: Once you provide a `ReadByte()` function, folks will start using it, mindlessly. Adding a cache merely guards against the most egregious consequences of publishing an API that's not well thought-out.